# Код одного ассета не видит namespace из другого ассета

Tags: c#, unity3d, namespace, assets

Столкнулся с проблемой. Есть два ассета. Я в коде одного пытаюсь подключить namespace другого. Но он его не видит. Это код ассета. Я подключаю mirror, но он его не видит
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее студия предлагает мне вариант решения
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В следствии чего ничего визуально не изменяется, но теперь mirror виден
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я вот не понимаю, что она сделала, то ли ссылку как то добавила, то ли еще что то.
Беда в том, что ошибка пропадает только в студии. В юнити как я понимаю они остаются не связанными. Так как выдается такая ошибка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при всем этом, когда я создаю свой скрипт в папке scripts у  меня mirror виден и юнька не ругается.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я так понимаю в unity надо связать эти ассеты или одному ассету кинуть ссылку на namespace другого. И если моя догадка верна, то как это сделать в unity

Структура файлов выглядит так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приведите код текстом, а не картинками.

Comment: Я понимаю, что код скринами мовитон, но в данном случае я показываю, что студия сначала отмечает ошибку, а потом нет

Comment: Согласен, невнимательно прочитал вопрос, подумав, что проблема в коде.

Comment: Приложите скриншоты содержимого папок ассетов. Либо, если знаете, что такое asmdef файлы, приложите скриншоты их инспектора.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Спасибо вам огромное. Благодаря вам я узнал о существовании asmdef и понял свою ошибку. Для решения моей проблемы, нужно было просто найти файл с расширением asmdef,  в ассете в котором я изменяю код, и в инспекторе, добавить ему ссылку на файл с расширением asmdef  из ассета который мне необходим. И все заработало

Comment: @user395494 оформите ответ, чтобы другие пользователи со схожим вопросом могли решить свою проблему не догадываясь, что там написано в комментариях :)

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, Спасибо за подсказку, оформил )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение оказалось простое. Нужно было просто найти файл с расширением asmdef, в ассете в котором я изменяю код, и в инспекторе, добавить ему ссылку на файл с расширением asmdef из ассета который мне необходим. И все заработало